# Train test split for ensuring all categories are included in train set

Tags: python, categorical-data, train-test-split

Let's say there are some 20 categorical columns in the data, each having a different set of unique categorical values. Now a train test split has to done, and one needs to ensure that all unique categories are included in the train set. How can it be done? I have not tried yet, but should all these columns be included in the stratify argument?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. That's correct.

For demonstration, I'm using [Melbourne Housing Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/dansbecker/melbourne-housing-snapshot/home).

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

Meta = pd.read_csv('melb_data.csv')
Meta = Meta[["Rooms", "Type", "Method", "Bathroom"]]
print(Meta.head())

print("\nBefore split -- Method feature distribution\n")
print(Meta.Method.value_counts(normalize=True))
print("\nBefore split -- Type feature distribution\n")
print(Meta.Type.value_counts(normalize=True))

train, test = train_test_split(Meta, test_size = 0.2, stratify=Meta[["Method", "Type"]])

print("\nAfter split -- Method feature distribution\n")
print(train.Method.value_counts(normalize=True))
print("\nAfter split -- Type feature distribution\n")
print(train.Type.value_counts(normalize=True))
```

Output

```
Rooms Type Method  Bathroom
0      2    h      S       1.0
1      2    h      S       1.0
2      3    h     SP       2.0
3      3    h     PI       2.0
4      4    h     VB       1.0

Before split -- Method feature distribution

S     0.664359
SP    0.125405
PI    0.115169
VB    0.088292
SA    0.006775
Name: Method, dtype: float64

Before split -- Type feature distribution

h    0.695803
u    0.222165
t    0.082032
Name: Type, dtype: float64

After split -- Method feature distribution

S     0.664396
SP    0.125368
PI    0.115151
VB    0.088273
SA    0.006811
Name: Method, dtype: float64

After split -- Type feature distribution

h    0.695784
u    0.222202
t    0.082014
Name: Type, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

you want all categories from all categorical variables to be in your train split.

Using :

```
train, test = train_test_split(Meta, test_size = 0.2, stratify=Meta[["Method", "Type"]])
```

ensure that all categories are in **the train split and test split**. This is more than what you want.

It has to be noticed that the more categorical variables you stratify on, the more probable it is that a combination of categories has only one record associated. If that case occurs, the split won't be done.

Error message :

```
ValueError: The least populated class in y has only 1 member, which is too few. The minimum number of groups for any class cannot be less than 2.
```